# How to check the CPU and memory load in percentages of a process then output that to a file?

Tags: file, ubuntu, process, load, output

I have searched with no luck. The onlything I am able to find is the entire servers load, which I do not want. I want to specifically check how much CPU and memory a process is using, preferably CPU in percentages and memory in MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the CPU and memory usage of a process using `ps`. If you know the pid of the process, then a command like this will give you the percentage CPU usage and memory usage in kilobytes:

```
ps -o pcpu,rss -p <pid>
```

You can redirect the output of this to a file in the usual way, and do whatever you want with it. Other variables that you can get in this way can be found in `man ps` (or [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ps.1.html)), in the section on Standard Format Specifiers.

Comment: Can I do this by process name instead of id?

Comment: Use "pgrep" first to get PID from process name.

Comment: You can turn it into a one-liner with `ps -o pcpu,rss -p \`pgrep <name>\``.